# SQL query to select 1 or all records in table with multiple filters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a more concise and readable way to write the T-SQL query in a stored procedure that will grant the procedure the capability of returning all records or just one record in a table?

Below is an approach that I'm familiar with which works.  In this example, the stored procedure will either return all States from a table, or just a single State, based on one or more filters.  Pass no filters and it returns all states.  Apply either a StateID or StateAbbreviation filter and it will return one record.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StateGet]

@StateID int = null,
@StateAbbreviation varchar(3) = null

AS

BEGIN

    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[State]
    WHERE
        CASE WHEN @StateID = StateID THEN 1
             WHEN @StateID IS NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END = 1
        AND
        CASE WHEN @StateAbbreviation = Abbreviation THEN 1
             WHEN @StateAbbreviation IS NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END = 1

    /*
    -- Return all states
    exec dbo.StateGet
    -- Return 1 state (Minnesota)
    exec dbo.StateGet 24
    exec dbo.StateGet NULL, 'MN'
    */

END
```

I'd like to use a more readable syntax than that shown above.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: `WHERE ISNULL(@StateID,StateID) = StateID AND ISNULL(@StateAbbreviation,Abbreviation) = Abbreviation`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code:

```
SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[State]
    WHERE (@StateID is null or @StateID = StateID)
          AND
          (@StateAbbreviation is null or @StateAbbreviation = Abbreviation)
```

if you pass `@StateAbbreviation` or `@StateAbbreviation` as null to stored procedure, it will ignored because of `or` operand between conditions.

> @StateID = null
>
> (@StateID is null or @StateID = StateID) => (true or anything) => true

Comment: Yep, that looks clearer to me. And I found a couple of articles about this as well at http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2003/11/14/513.aspx and http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/09/18/sql-conditional-where-clauses.aspx.  Thanks Mohamad.